# What's the difference between StreamTableEnvironment#toDataStream and toAppendStream

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading the source code of `StreamTableEnvironment`, it has two methods: `toDataStream` and `toAppendStream` .

Both of these two methods only work with table whose rows are of `RowKind.INSERT`,that is,both methods are to convert the table to appending stream.

I would ask what's the key difference for these two methods, I think they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toAppendStream` is legacy that will be deprecated in the next Flink version. The reason why it is not deprecated yet is that we wanted to give `toDataStream` more exposure and stability which happened in 1.13.1.

The differences are not directly visible but exist. For example, structured POJO types are handled differently.

Comment: Sure， thanks @twalthr for the helpful answer!